# Can i give to an attribute a complex name?

Tags: knockout.js

In general if someone wants to set an attribute of an html element he has to write something like

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: url }">
```

However in my case I want the value of the src to be a combination of url and a string that i define.How can I achieve it? Ideally I would be happy if I could write

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: url+"/image.jpeg" }">
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Please define "does not work"! By the way it should work if you are using `'` so `<img data-bind="attr: { src: url+'/image.jpeg' }">`

Comment: "does not work" -> not have the desire functionality aka can get a url attribute by this way.But the solution finally was simple:single quotes! thank u very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: url+'/image.jpeg' }">
```

As identified in comments. Use single quotes.